# Want a Second Look Do all of these Capacitors Need to be Changed?

Tags: capacitor, repair

I pulled apart my monitor to check the capacitors and I think almost all of them need to be replaced but there are a couple I am not sure about

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like shaving foam :-)

Comment: Do not change the first surface mount capacistor you say might be OK, its not on the power supply part so it should really be ok. Replace the bulged "large" capacitor and you should be find, this is the most common reason for failure in monitors.

Comment: Please crop and scale your images to more useful sizes (max 630px wide). Mind our mobile internet users.

Comment: -1 for posting absurdly large images.

Comment: @Gunnish - actually, that SMD capacitor *is* a power supply part.  Notice it's right next to the board's regulator.  And there's little other reason than as part of the power supply for such a capacitor to be found on a digital board.

Comment: +1 for posting large clear pictures to make visual inspection of the potential defects that are the subject of the post possible.

Comment: @ChrisStratton ok yes, but it is for the powersupply of the digital circuit, not the CFL or the lcd matrix itself. That part doesn't usually break. Ive repaired 8 LCD the same way, always the matrix/CFL capacitors. That, however, doesn't mean that it is impossible for other things to break, just that it is probably less likely.

Answer (score 3):

The white goop in your photos is not something that exploded out of the capacitors. It's something like a potting compound, and if I guess right, it has a kind-of rubbery consistency.

I suspect it's there to prevent the tall parts from being bent over to where they touch the heatsinks next to them. If that were to happen, those capacitors could be overheated and their lifetime would be shortened considerably.

I've seen similar compounds used more commonly on tall parts to dampen physical vibrations which could wear out the leads over time, but given all the other tall parts on your board that don't have the goop on them, that's probably not what's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to replace all the electrolytic capacitors.

On your first picture, the central IC/microcontroller has a sticker on it with a "2007.9.7" marking. It might be the date of manufacture or assembly. Most electrolytic capacitors made around 2002 to 2010 in Taiwan/Hong Kong/China were known for early failure: dubbed the "[capacitor plague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague)". The "[CapXon](http://www.capxongroup.com/en/about_page.aspx?catid=about&itemid=1173)" brand of capacitors is from a manufacturer in Taiwan and Google search for "[capxon bad capacitors](https://www.google.com/search?q=capxon%20bad%20capacitors)" is picking up a lot of hits (9,140 results).

I suggest that you replace all the capacitors including those that doesn't look bad. They all probably came in one batch and from one manufacturer. Those that hasn't failed yet is most likely to fail soon - and worse, taking [Murphy's admonition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law), cause catastrophic circuit failure. So save yourself of that trouble and of having to disassemble the device again by replacing everything including the surface mount capacitors in the first picture (the one you marked "OK???"). Those are surface mount electrolytic capacitors. As a legal maxim goes, "falsus in uno, falsus in omnibus" or false in one, false in all: if the CapXon capacitors can't be trusted, the rest of the components may also be of shoddy manufacture.

Answer (score 1):

Bulging is the obvious sign that a capacitor has failed, so those will need replacement. The one marked "what happened here" just looks like it's been physically pushed over during assembly or disassembly. There is no way to reliably test a capacitor in-circuit that I'm aware of and you really need to remove to measure ESR and capacitance.

You should be aware that the failure mode of capacitors includes being open, shorted, low capacitance and high ESR and depending on their usage any of those (especially a short) often will damage other components so it's not likely to be as simple as just replacing all the caps.

Answer (score 0):

From your images it is the first one and the last two that you are questioning? Any physical deformity, such as in the first, suggested needed replacement. I cant' quick make out what is going on in the last picture.

Answer (score 0):

You have disassembled the unit entirely. Don't try to save 1 or 2 Euro's/Dollars by leaving not replacing a few of them. The others may very well fail soon too and you'll have to do the whole operation again. Replace them all, especially since it looks like they are all the same brand.

Hopefully the rest of the circuit didn't get damaged due to the bad caps. I'm really curious why so many are in such bad shape.

Comment: As to why, power supply capacitor failures are too common on LCD monitors and changing them usually fixes the monitor. Probably poor design, but perhaps bad capacitors. Changing them all is good advice.